# wxFrame and wxTaskBarIcon taskbar event Mac OSX : callback not being triggered

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

I have a derived class for `wxFrame` (MyFrame) (for OSX - Yosemite platform), where it calls:
    Bind(wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_DOWN), &HandleTaskBarEvent, this);

The issue is `HandleTaskBarEvent` is not being invoked when I right click the icon in the dock.

I see the generic right click menu that Mac has (Open at Login, Keep in Dock, etc) for the main icon in the dock.

Also, I created a `wxTaskBarIcon`. I am guessing this will be utilized for the minimized icon in the dock after the frame is minimized.

```
systemIcon = new wxTaskBarIcon(); //declared in header
systemIcon.Bind(wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_DOWN, &HandleTaskBarEvent, this);
Popup = new wxMenu(); //declared in header
QuitMenu = new wxMenuItem(Popup, wxID_ANY, wxString(wxT("Quit")), wxEmptyString, wxITEM_NORMAL); //declared in header
Popup->Append(QuitMenu)
Popup->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &CloseFunc, this, QuitMenu->GetId());
```

This is inside the same derived class(MyFrame).

I call `Iconize()` inside that MyFrame same function, which works as expected. It minimized the window.

This is the `HandleTaskBarEvent` function (virtual)

```
void MyFrame::HandleTaskBarEvent(wxTaskBarIconEvent& event)
{
    if(event.GetEventType() == wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_DOWN)
    {
        systemIcon->PopupMenu(Popup);
    }
}
```

I saw this post : [Mouse Events of WxPython TaskBarIcon on Mac OSX are not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884467/mouse-events-of-wxpython-taskbaricon-on-mac-osx-are-not-triggering)
and there seems to be a bug about it. But I am not able to find that bug or its status online. It is mentioned that the issue is with wxPython, but seems related to my problem.

Also I created a derived class for wxTaskBarIcon and overrode CreatePopupMenu and made systemIcon as an instance of MyTaskBarIcon, but that function is not being triggered for any clicks(left,right, etc). Also the main wxFrame 's Bind callback (HandleTaskBarEvent) is not being triggered, hence the systemIcon is not being able to popup the menu.

I am not using mouse for my Mac (using trackpad instead). Not sure if it should make any difference to right click code, but adding the information here anyways.

So I am thinking this could be wxWidget-OSX specific issue, because the code works on Windows as expected.

Does anyone know if this is purely wxWidget-OSX incomplete feature, if there is any open bugs about it, and more importantly if there is any solution to show the popup menu items for the minimized icon in the dock, and to handle the click events for the menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `&HandleTaskBarEvent` should be rejected by the compiler. Aren't you getting any diagnostic messages when compiling?

Comment: No, not getting warning or errors in that line during compilation. Also I am using &MyFrame::HandleTaskBarEvent. sorry missed the class specifier in the front.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the OS X `wxTaskBarIcon` implementation. See [wxTaskBarIcon on OSX - two-finger click does not send mouse event](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14646) and related/linked issues.

The only way I know of (on OS X) is overriding [wxTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_task_bar_icon.html#a739c81dc5cadf9e550d38001cee419f6).

You should be able to have something like:

```
  MyApp::wxApp/
    MyTaskBarIcon::wxTaskBarIcon (override CreatePopupMenu(), return a new wxMenu)
```

This is the model I use in a few applications and it works the same on Windows and OS X (albeit no specific click handlers as mentioned).

Comment: Hi, I came across that , and overrode CreatePopupMenu for wxTaskBarIcon, but the main Frame( derived class of wxFrame) 's bind methods for task bar events were itself not working.

Comment: Right - Most of them do not function on OS X (ie: not implemented). See the linked bug.