# wxPython 4.0.6 in OSX - Clicking on Menubar icon is not triggering events

Tags: python, macos, events, wxpython, menubar

I have been searching for why `wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_UP` event is not triggering in Mac OSX, it is fine in Windows.
Tray icon in Windows but I believe it is called Menubar in OSX.
Icon is displayed in Menubar right corner but when it is clicked event will not fire. Also tried `EVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP` and `EVT_TASKBAR_CLICK`.

Found this old thread about the same issue.
[Mouse Events of WxPython TaskBarIcon on Mac OSX are not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884467/mouse-events-of-wxpython-taskbaricon-on-mac-osx-are-not-triggering) maybe this bug hasn't been fixed?

Anyone that has had the same issue and has figured this out?

I'm using python 2.7 and wxPython 4.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX the `TaskBarIcon` is only able to show a popup menu, and you need to override the `CreatePopMenu` method to provide the menu to be displayed. See the demo’s `Main.py` module so see an example.